# Enable pulseaudio equalizer only for bluetooth headsets

Tags: bluetooth, pulse-audio, equalizer

I'm using pulseaudio with the LADSPA equalizer. I want to enable the equalizer only when my bluetooth headset is connected. The behaviour at the moment is that when I disconnect the headset, the equalizer stays enabled for the internal speakers, but when I connect again, the equalizer is not automatically re-enabled for this sink.

Is there a configuration option or another way to tell pulseaudio to enable the equalizer only for the blueooth headset, but always enable it automatically for that?